# Identify Keccak Algorithm

Tags: algorithm-design, keccak

I need to analyse a binary code and check if Keccak is used in this code.
I can identify AES, by using Rijndael S-box. Is there a similiar box for Keccak?

Comment: Well, the Keccak permutation should be pretty unique and be somewhat easily identifiable...

Comment: The most distinct thing about Keccak internally that I have seen is the A XOR (!B & C) function immediately prior to XOR with the round constant. It does not have substitution boxes like AES, and it is not ARX either, though it is similar to the latter.

Be careful searching AES by substitution box. Other algorithms now borrow the AES S-Boxes and could yield false positives.

Answer (score 1):

I just found the ["round constants"](https://keccak.team/keccak_specs_summary.html#roundConstants) which hopefully are sufficiently unique to allow identification of the algorithm.

Comment: the constants in a 32-bit implementation may not be the same as the reference code